# Plus-minus signs in function definitions

Tags: functions

Consider $$f(x)=\pm x$$
Then is $f$ a multivalued function? It may seems like it is, but since there is a $\pm$ sign, we can write this in two expressions: $$f(x)=x\; \text{or}\;f(x)=-x$$
In each equation, $f(x)$ only yields one value. This shows that $f(x)$ is a single-valued function.

Answer (score 2):

This notation makes no sense. 
This is not even a function, because you did not define what the domain and range of $f$ is supposed to be.

This can be fixed easily, but $f(x)=\pm x$ would only make sense if the only value in the domain is $0$.
The function value $f(x)$ has to be unique. You can not map $x$ onto two different $f(x)$ values.

You might want to define $f$ by cases:

$f(x)=\begin{cases} -x,~\text{if}~ x\geq 0\\ x,~\text{if}~ x<0\end{cases}$

An example function would look like this:

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=\begin{cases} -x,~\text{if}~ x\geq 0\\ x,~\text{if}~ x<0\end{cases}$